# Need help understanding $scope inheritance (and adding newly generated content to Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing my first app using AngularJS, and I'm stuck at some point where I need to share data across different controllers.

I have something like this :

```
function ctrl1 ($scope) {
  $scope.data = new Object();
}

function ctrl2 ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('my_page').success(function(html) {
    // I set some values to the parent's data object
    $scope.data['my_key'] = 'My value';
    // The html loaded here contains a ng-controller='ctrl3' somewhere
    $('#mydiv').html(html);
    // So I bootstrap it
    angular.bootstrap($('#mydiv'), ['my_module']);
  });
}

// Is not a child of ctrl2, but is a child of ctrl1
function ctrl3 ($scope) {
  $scope.my_key = $scope.data.my_key; // Cannot read property 'my_key' of undefined 
  // And in an ng-repeat where I want to display my_key, nothing is shown. 
  // However, if I manually set my_key here, everything is displayed correctly.
  // So the controller and ng-repeat are correctly parsed after bootstrapping
}
```

Here is the HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl1">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl2">
    <!-- some content -->
  </div>
  <!-- some more code -->
  <div id="myDiv">
    <!-- currently empty, will be added html with AJAX, ang ng-controller="ctrl3" is in this (as well as my ng-repeat) -->
  </div>
</div>
```

According to [this very nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14049482/1287598), I should be able to read and set properties of `data` if it's not set in the child scope and is set in the parent scope.

Why isn't this working?

[EDIT]

Figured it out now, here's the solution. I had to inject [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile) into my `ctrl2` and compile the code with it before adding it to the DOM.

```
function ctrl2 ($scope, $http, $compile) {
  $http.get('my_page').success(function(html) {
    // I set some values to the parent's data object
    $scope.data['my_key'] = 'My value';
    // The html loaded here contains a ng-controller='ctrl3' somewhere
    // ** Have to compile it before appending to the DOM
    $('#mydiv').html($compile(html)($scope));
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you include the HTML? I'm guessing you have sibling scoping, but it really depends on how and where these controllers are attached.

Comment: I added some HTML, which reflects the actual structure of my document

Comment: Scope inheritance in this way should work. Create a plunk or fiddle to show what isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're seeing here isn't scope inheritance, the problem is your call to `angular.bootstrap`:

```
angular.bootstrap($('#myDiv'), ['my_module']);
```

This is telling angular that the root DOM element of the app is the `#myDiv`, so your `ng-controller="ctrl1"` and `ng-controller="ctrl2"` aren't considered as part of this app. Therefore you don't get expected result.

Fix:

```
<div id="myContainer" ng-controller="ctrl1">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl2">
    <!-- some content -->
  </div>
  <!-- some more code -->
  <div id="myDiv">
    <!-- currently empty, will be added html with AJAX, ang ng-controller="ctrl3" is in this (as well as my ng-repeat) -->
  </div>
</div>
```

and in JS:

```
angular.bootstrap($('#myContainer'), ['my_module']);
```

Comment: That's not the issue here. He'd still have no way to pass data between controller scopes.

Comment: ctrl2's scope is a child of ctrl1's scope, **scope inheritance** works. Read the other SO answer linked in PO's question if you're interested in this topic.

Comment: Looks like you put the finger on the problem! I added an `ng-init` along with `ng-controller="ctrl3"`. Looks like it parses it when I call `bootstrap` on my root, but now I have two problems. 1. It calls all the other `ng-init` again, which is pretty bad for me right now, and 2. It seems any key added to data from ctrl2 is not available from ctrl3...

Comment: Please update your original question with those progress, new code, new html templates, and ask more questions from there

Comment: I've figured it out, and the problem was not about the inheritance not working, but more about the way I added the newly created code to Angular. I edited my first post to show the solution. However your solution was the closest to being the right one!

Answer (score 1):

You can either build some sort of service helper, or you can use the built in [$on](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24on) and [$broadcast](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24broadcast) to pass data between scopes.

e.g. Set & pass data

```
$scope.functionName = function () {
 $scope.message = "This is a message, string, object or whatever";
 $rootScope.$broadcast('message', message);
};
```

Catch broadcast in another controller

```
    $scope.$on('message', function(message){
     $scope.message = message;

     // You now have access to message 
   });
```

There's a more elegant way of doing this so you don't have to pollute `$rootScope`, but I can't remember how to do it right now.

Added example. http://jsfiddle.net/vPq2P/3/

Comment: This is right. Though using the service helper might be a cleaner way to do it. Create a service module, and you can inject any variables defined within the module into your controllers.